# Stacks and Queues exam follow through

Tags: java

I'm going through a sample exam paper I was given in order to prepare for the real one. I'm pretty sure I'm answering the question wrong anyway, if you guys could indicate me where I'm going wrong that'd be really cool. But try and be descriptive so I can manipulate different values to actually get an understanding!

Sorry about the [link](http://vvcap.net/db/8P8I4pXIxeZXm74xbcdi.htp) unsure how to convert it so it displays as an Image here if someone could do that for me I'd appreciate it.

Anyway the first value is "1 2"

I'll go through my attempt:

1. The first.push line is adding it onto the Stack, as well as converting it from a String to an int.
2. Since it's not empty we follow the try for the Stack named first
3. This is where I think I may be going wrong - value = first.pop(); 
   Since a stack is last in first out, I'm assuming the result of value will be 2 
   since "1 2" 2 comes in last so it's the most recent...
4. 2%2 == 0 so we now add value to the list which is 2 but since it's second.offer(value/2); 
   this would make it 0, therefore it has no value ? making it null?
5. we skip the catch since everything has ran smoothly ...
6. See here I'm unsure because I guess second is empty since we added 0 ?

I'm pretty confused and I'm sure I've went wrong somewhere. I'd really appreciate it if you guys could help me follow through it, as it'll almost definitely show up on my exam.

Comment: value/2 i.e 2/2=1 right ?!

Comment: You're misunderstanding #4. The code (value%2 == 0) is checking for even numbers and ignoring odd, which is as you say. But, (value / 2) will give you 1, not 0. [i.e. 2 / 2 = 1]. Also, even if the calculation were something that gave you a 0, that is not the same as a null.

Answer (score 1):

I think #4 might be wrong, 2/2 should be 1, not 0?

Also, don't confuse 0 and null. 0 is a perfectly good value, just like 1 or 2.
Also a primitive int don't get to be null. It always contain an integer. Offering
0 to a queue should be perfectly fine.

edit in response to comment:

"2 0 4" contains many even elements. To answer this question you have
to know a little bit about the queue class, and specifically the poll method.
You should note that the poll is done in a loop, continuing until the queue
is empty. If the poll method removes the element from the queue (which seems likely)
then it should print out all the elements in the queue, right? So your answer should
likely contain more than one element.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I made that error lol. Can anyone confirm that the answer is 1?

Comment: Of course 2/2 = 1. it is basic mathematics. Result from division is 0 only if you are dividing by 0.

Comment: Yeah, I know I made a mathematical error... But I'd still like to know whether I followed through the program correctly ?

Comment: Well, I think you have the basic idea right. If you want to increase your understanding I suggest you think a little bit more about why adding 0 to a queue makes as much sense as adding 1 to it. This is unrelated to this example, but still important.

Comment: Thanks. For "2 0 4", I got the answer 2 is that correct ?

Comment: Added answer to this.